# Blank new Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms project doesn't run on emulator API 15 or 16

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to test something in API 15 or 16 in emulator but xamarin seem to not work in any of these emulators, although it works in emulators with API 24 and above. and also runs fine on actual devices with API 15 or 16.

I don't get anything in logcat only this in output window:

```
InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: Start -> EntryPointBreakpointRegistered
InspectorDebugSession(0): Constructed
Android application is debugging.
Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited
InspectorDebugSession(0): Disposed
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to test something in API 15 or 16 in emulator but xamarin seem to not work in any of these emulators, although it works in emulators with API 24 and above. and also runs fine on actual devices with API 15 or 16.

I've had the same issue before, and I got it fixed by disable the fast deployment mode:

Right click your project->Properties->Android Options->uncheck "Use Fast Deployment(debug mode only)"

Comment: thanks worked, I've been looking for a solution to this everywhere for about a week :)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this is just a dependecy problems,  as you know when you update one component theres others than need to be update it too.

My recomendarion is that go to nuget package, delete xamarin forms from your .droid. (no update it)

Clean the solution

Install xamarin.forms again and those will correct your problem, let me know if it

Comment: I tested with a xamarin.android project (no xamarin.forms nuget package) and it still doesn't run :(

Comment: damm, do you test in vs 2017   ?